# Firefox change newtab focus settings

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

When I <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to open a new tab `about:blank` firefox used to focus address bar, now it doesn't focus anything. Starting to type in new tab won't do anything.

> How can I change it to focus address bar on open?

It all started after I got rid of some irritating Delta search.

Comment: Are you typing 'about:blank' into the address bar or is that what the new tab is set to show>

Comment: @BradPatton yes, it is set to show this page when opening new tab. When I input empty string to newtab setting, the behaviour is just the same.

Comment: The value for 'browser.newtab.url' is set to 'about:newtab' for me. And focus goes to the address bar. Is this an option for you.

Comment: No, 9 panels show, but the focus is still nowhere. It all started with the Delta search which got installed I don't remember how. I will try turning off all extensions or maybe reinstalling ff.

Comment: What is 'accessibility.tabfocus' and 'accessibility.tabfocus_applies_to_xul' set to?

Comment: It is set to 7 and false, not sure what it refers to. I checked many articles about messing with some true|false values, but it all applied only to focusing search bar instead. turns out that it was caused by Daemon Tools Lite.

Comment: This is a duplicate in my eyes, however you found another solution to the duplicate question.  I suggest adding your answer to the duplicate instead of editing your question to reflect the answer.

Comment: I've also rolled back your edit.  Any comments to others should be just that, comments.  Also any answers should be posted as answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to cycle through all of the focus spots. You might have to press it up to 5-6 times depending on where focus initially lands.

Comment: Your question said 'How can I change it to focus address bar again?' you can use the Tab key to do that. Did you mean how can I can have it default the focus there?